# Error al leer el resultado de una petición POST con Jersey 2

Tags: java, http, jersey

Estoy desarrollando un cliente HTTP con Jersey, para lo que utilizo las siguientes dependencias:

- 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.23.2'
- 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.23.2'

El servicio web realiza correctamente su tarea cuando recibe la petición POST, que no es más que almacenar una entidad y devolver la entidad que ha creado (He estado probando con POSTMAN y funciona correctamente).

El problema reside en el cliente, al leer la respuesta del servidor:

```
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig).register(JacksonFeature.class);
    WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI()).path(path);
    License license = new License("000011111");

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response res = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(license, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    License resLicense = null;
    if (res.getStatus() == 200)
        resLicense = res.readEntity(License.class);
    return resLicense;
```

Cuando intento convertir la respuesta (`resLicense = res.readEntity(License.class);`), Jersey lanza la siguiente Excepción:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed.
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.ensureNotClosed(EntityInputStream.java:228)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:854)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:115)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:112)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.license.http.HttpClient.doRequest(HttpClient.java:39)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.license.services.impl.WebLicenseService.activate(WebLicenseService.java:14)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.license.LicenseChecker.activateLicense(LicenseChecker.java:25)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.license.LicenseController.activate(LicenseController.java:24)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.webapp.licencia.LicenciaBean.activarLicencia(LicenciaBean.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
    net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.webapp.servicios.filters.PushFilter.doFilter(PushFilter.java:32)
    es.kestrel.monitorizador.webapp.servicios.filters.LicenseFilter.doFilter(LicenseFilter.java:34)
```

Nota: La entidad de la respuesta coincide con la estructura de la clase "`License`".

## Actualización

Tras realizar varias pruebas, he detectado que este error solo ocurre cuando ejecuto la aplicación en modo de depuración, pues cuando la ejecuto de modo normal funciona correctamente.

Comment: El error significa que alguien o algo ha consumido la respuesta de la ejecución de tu solicitud HTTP. Al parecer, antes de ejecutar `res.readEntity` lo puedes haber leído desde otro método, por ende el stream de la respuesta ya se encuentra cerrado y no puede ser leído nuevamente. ¿Estás seguro que ese es todo el código provisto y que tu request tipo POST devuelve datos que se pueden leer? ¿Has intentado probar con otro cliente HTTP como unirest?

Comment: Tras hacer varias pruebas, he llegado a la conclusión que este error solo ocurre cuando ejecuto la aplicación en modo depuración, ya que si ejecuto la aplicación de modo normal funciona correctamente, aunque no se muy bien a que se debe este problema.

Comment: Sucede que cuando depuras e intentas leer el resultado, el stream de datos ya se habrá consumido por algún agente, por ello al ejecutar `readEntity` va a fallar puesto que ese stream ya se consumió.

Comment: Cuando se realizan consultas por red se crean sockets de comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor, al parecer lo que está sucediendo es que el socket se cerró cuando intentas leer/escribir, probablemente por un timeout del canal de comunicación, puede ser porque cuando estás depurando y por consecuencia ejecutas linea a linea esa demora(tiempo) ocasiona que se cierre el socket, intenta poner el punto de interrupción después de ése código mostrado, no antes. Espero que ayude a entender mejor lo que está pasando.